# play-silhouette-seed 4.0.0 でのsignup時のmysqlへのinsert

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, mariadb, scalikejdbc

[play-silhouette-seed 4.0.0](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/tree/4.0.0) を使ったsignupの際に、同時にmysqlへinsertしたいと考えているのですが、エラーは出ていないものの、mysqlのcolumnには記録されていない状況です。(5/20 追加; insertした際のログも出ないので、sql文が実行されていないと思われます）

なお手を加えるにあたり、以前いただいたご回答を参考にさせていただいています。
[ProvisionException: Unable to provision / Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43546/provisionexception-unable-to-provision-error-injecting-constructor-java-lang)

関連するファイルは以下になります。

flywayを使ったmigration ( V1__create_tables.sql )

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer1`;
CREATE TABLE `customer1` (
  `pk`                    BIGINT        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id`                    BIGINT        NOT NULL,
  `name`                  VARCHAR(256)  NOT NULL,
  `email`                 VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
  `password`              VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`pk`),
  UNIQUE(`id`)
);
```

(application.conf) DB関連部分のみ載せてあります

```
include "silhouette.conf"

play.modules {

 enabled += "modules.BaseModule"
 enabled += "modules.JobModule"
 enabled += "modules.SilhouetteModule"
 enabled += "play.api.libs.mailer.MailerModule"

 disabled += "com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.SecuredErrorHandlerModule"
 disabled += "com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.UnsecuredErrorHandlerModule"

 enabled += "scalikejdbc.PlayModule"
 enabled += "scalikejdbc.PlayDBApiAdapterModule"
 #enabled += "play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule"
 enabled += "org.flywaydb.play.PlayModule"

 play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
 }

db {

   default.driver="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
   default.url="jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/spetstore?characterEncoding=utf8"
   default.username= admin
   default.password= admin

   default.poolInitialSize = 10
   default.poolMaxSize = 10
   default.poolValidationQuery = "select 1 as one"

 }

 scalikejdbc {
   global {
     loggingSQLAndTime.enabled = true
     loggingSQLAndTime.singleLineMode = true
     loggingSQLAndTime.logLevel = DEBUG
     loggingSQLAndTime.warningEnabled = true
     loggingSQLAndTime.warningThresholdMillis = 5
     loggingSQLAndTime.warningLogLevel = warn
   }
 }
```

(signupcontroller.scala)  左のファイルは手を加えていません。

(signupform.scala)

```
package forms

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

/**
 * The form which handles the sign up process.
 */
object SignUpForm {

  /**
   * A play framework form.
   */
   val form = Form(
     mapping(
       "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
       "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
       "email" -> email,
       "password" -> nonEmptyText
     )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
   )

   /**    
    * The form data. 
    *     
    * @param firstName The first name of a user.
    * @param lastName The last name of a user.
    * @param email The email of the user.
    * @param password The password of the user.
    */
  case class Data(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String)
```

//      以下の一文を追加. dbへのinsert

```
    def insert(data: Data): Unit = SignUpFormSupport.insert(data)
}
```

(signupformsupport.scala) 自身で追加したファイル。　mysqlへのinsertにはscalikejdbcを使っています。

```
package forms

import java.util.UUID
import javax.inject.Inject

import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api._
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.repositories.AuthInfoRepository
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.services.AvatarService
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.util.PasswordHasherRegistry
import com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers._
import models.User
import models.services.{ AuthTokenService, UserService }
import org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil
import play.api.i18n.{ I18nSupport, Messages }
import play.api.libs.mailer.{ Email, MailerClient }

import play.api.mvc._
import utils.auth.DefaultEnv

import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import java.sql.Connection
import scalikejdbc._
import scalikejdbc.SQLInterpolation._

import forms.SignUpForm.Data     

object SignUpFormSupport { 



  /** 登録 */
   def insert(data: Data): Unit = {

    try {

       DB localTx { implicit session =>

       import data._

        val id = System.currentTimeMillis()

         sql"""insert into customer1 (id, `name`, email, `password`)
              |values ($id,  ${firstName + lastName}, $email, $password)"""
          .stripMargin
          .update
          .apply()

      }

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    }

   }

}
```

signupform.scala で、objectの中に case class が入っているのに対し、signupformsupport.scala のimport文が正しく書けているかもわかりません。

ご回答いただければ幸いです。

5/20 その後engineがInnoDBになっていないのかどうかも確認しましたが、問題なくdefaultになっているようです。

一つ気になっている点として、上記のファイルはcontrollerではないですが、前回同様の実装をした折はcontrollerでした。ただフォームで得た変数を渡すだけのメソッドしかmodelsのファイルには記していないため、controllerである必要はないだろうと考えているのですが、その点はいかがでしょうか。（もっとも、フォームのファイルをcontrollerにしようとすると、signupcontroller.scalaのほうにフォームを記さなくては無くなりそうで、seedの構成を壊してしまいそうです。）

またその後試しにSignUpController.scalaのほうに、

```
  import forms.SignUpForm._
  // dbへのinsert
  def insert(data: Data): Unit = SignUpFormSupport.insert(data)
```

を加え、SignUpForm.scalaの方をコメントアウトしてみたものの、やはり状況に変化はありませんでした。

5/21 ドキュメント( https://www.playframework.com/documentation/ja/2.4.x/ScalaForms) に、

> email: scala.String にマッピングされ、電子メールの正規表現を使用します。

の一文があり、

```
        val email2 = email.toString

        sql"""insert into customer1 (id, `name`, email, `password`)
              |values ($id,  ${firstName + lastName}, $email2, $password)"""
          .stripMargin
          .update
          .apply()
```

としてみたものの、やはり変化はありません。また、ログを見ると、

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at   jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/spetstore?characterEncoding=utf8
[debug] application - Directory for migration files found. db/migration/default
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

とあるため、当たり前ではありますがmariadb自体は動いており、migrationもできている状況です。

5/23 解決しました。

以下のようにSignUpController.scalaを書き換えることで無事挿入できました。

```
          case None =>
             //(中略)
            SignUpFormSupport.insert(data)
```

Comment: 解決しました。

以下のようにSignUpController.scalaを書き換えることで無事挿入できました。挿入するcaseを間違えていました

              case None =>
                 (中略)
                SignUpFormSupport.insert(data)

Comment: 自己解決した場合には質問文に直接追記するのではなく、個別に「回答」として投稿してもらえると、他の人が参照した時にも分かりやすくなると思います。

Comment: >cubickさん コメントありがとうございます。使い方が不慣れで申し訳ありません。次回以降そうします。